# Pop to rootViewController and then load a new viewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a login screen(embeded in navigation controller) with 2 buttons: "Register" & "Login".
When the user press register and has successfully registered I want to to load the Login controller.

What I have in mind:
1) Draw a segue from RegisterVC to LoginVC and by pass the rootVC. This is not seems right to me

2)Save a property in NSDefaults then poptoNVC from register and have the viewWillAppear to check if it will executed the segue to LoginVC automatically.This is also does not seems to me right.

Is there any way to get a pointer to rootVC from RegisterVC executed the poptoNVC and as soon as poptoNVC is finished use the pointer to execute a segue to login?
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to open the **register view controller** with

`presentViewController` (or use segue) type `modal` instead `push` the viewController.

When you dismiss the `registerViewController`, use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [_delegate goToLogin];
}];
```

so basically you can use the **delegation pattern** to say to the `rootViewController` (that is the `delegate`) that the `registerViewController` is dismissed and can access to the `loginViewController`.

OR: You can use your check in `viewWillAppear` but is not elegant for me.

Comment: thanks for your answer but using modal is not an option